# How many The Outer Limits comics were published in the 60s?

Tags: comics

In the 1960s there were [*The Outer Limits* comics](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=outer%20limits%20comics&tbm=isch) published every few months.

How many comics were published in total and across which period? Was it between 1964-1969?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

18 issues total. (I looked up full sets of the comic) The last was written in October of 1969.

Comment: Here is one place online where all 18 issues are listed: https://atomicavenue.com/title/11672/The-Outer-Limits

Comment: Could you expand this answer with some back-up for how long the comic series was? Perhaps with a link to where you "looked up full sets of the comic". (Don't use the link in the comment above this one; it's broken)